# Periodic update of macports

Tags: software-update, macports

Yet again it happened. I forgot to update my `macports` and I'm wasting hours...

How can I automatically run

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
sudo port -v upgrade outdated
```

Let say every week? Note that it has to be ran as `root`...

How do you maintain you `macports` up-to-date?

Is something like suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/173930/168219) is a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to run commands at regular intervals is you use [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/launchd.8.html)

An easy way is to use tools like [Lingon X](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) or [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) to maintain the  daemon/agent configuration file.

You can also do this without the tool by creating the file with a plain editor. To run as root you will need a .plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons. This needs you to provide the script and its arguments and will run as root.

In your case create a script to run both updates

```
port -v selfupdate
port -v upgrade outdated
```

[Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) gives an example to run a script called happybirthday as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.happybirthday</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>happybirthday</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Day</key>
        <integer>11</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Month</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```